# Warning while using asscalar

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Was using this asscalar to remove array for the output after using this asacalar i am encountered with warning

p1=np.asscalar(x_P_n[:1])

DeprecationWarning: np.asscalar(a) is deprecated since NumPy v1.16, use a.item() instead

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `a.item()`?

Comment: p1=a.item(x_P_n[:1]) sorry i am new to python                                                              do you mean this?

Comment: It says instead of `np.asscalar(a)` use `a.item()`. So in your case: `x_P_n[:1].item()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Deprecation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/) means the function you're using "*may be removed from a future Python release.*"

You should replace the function `np.asscalar(a)` with the suggested `a.item()` function to prevent your code from not working in the future. Please note that `a` represents your numpy array.

In this case, replacing
`np.asscalar(your_numpy_array)` with `your_numpy_array.item()`.